# Docker use Multiple nginx server with single php instance

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have several websites using php, each website is on a different docker.
In normal case, out of docker, all the websites use the same php installation.
How can that be achieved with docker?

this is my current setup. my single nginx docker uses this docker instance. (php-fpm.dockerfile only installing php-mysql).

```
  php:
    env_file: ".env"
    build :
      context : .
      dockerfile : php-fpm.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./server/www/:/var/www/:cached"
```

I want to add another nginx server using this php instance, is it possible?

this is my entire relevant yml file, `nginx_server` instance us using php, how can i tell the `php` instance to process `nginx_site` instance as well.

```
version: "3.5"

 nginx_server: 
    image: nginx
    env_file: ".env"
    links: 
      - php
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    restart: 
      always
    volumes :
      - "./server/nginx/default.conf.php.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template"
      - "./server/logs/:/var/log/nginx/:cached"
      - "./server/www/:/var/www/:cached"

    command : /bin/bash -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST,$$NGINX_ROOT,$$NGINX_INDEX_FILE,$$NGINX_PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=$NGINX_SERVER_HOST
      - NGINX_ROOT=$NGINX_SERVER_ROOT/public
      - NGINX_INDEX_FILE=index.php
      - NGINX_PORT=8081

  nginx_site:
      image: nginx
      env_file: ".env"
      links:
        - php
        - mysql
      ports:
        - "8082:80"
      restart:
        always
      volumes :
        - "./site/nginx/default.conf.php.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template"
        - "./site/logs/:/var/log/nginx/:cached"
        - "./site/www/:/var/www/:cached"

      command : /bin/bash -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST,$$NGINX_ROOT,$$NGINX_INDEX_FILE,$$NGINX_PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

      environment:
        - NGINX_HOST=$NGINX_SITE_HOST
        - NGINX_ROOT=/var/www/
        - NGINX_INDEX_FILE=index.php
        - NGINX_PORT=8082

  php:
    env_file: ".env"
    build :
      context : .
      dockerfile : php-fpm.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./server/www/:/var/www/:cached"
```

thanks

Comment: Unless your different websites share data (and I don't mean the same database) then surely having each one in a separate container is exactly what Docker is intended for - keeping separate things separate.

Comment: @NigelRen so the best practice is to have one php per website?

Comment: If the code on websites don't interact then IMHO - yes.  Also means if 1 website has a problem, the other sites shouldn't be affected.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks, ill wait for more comments. but it make sense.